# Energy of polyatomic molecular vibrations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, vibrations, molecules, molecular-dynamics

I understand that the energies of a simple diatomic molecular vibration are equal to $E_n=(n+\frac12)\hbar\omega$, and I also know the accompanying eigenfunctions for these energies. I have also heard it said, vaguely, that the vibrational states of polyatomic molecules are much more complicated. My question is: does the basic relationship that the excited states have energies equal to $3$, $5$, $7$, etc. times the ground state vibrational energy still hold for polyatomic molecules? For instance, if there is some complicated vibrational mode (which made be a bending, scissoring, or any other kind of mode) in  a polyatomic molecule with frequency $1.5$ THz, can we be sure that the excited vibrational states will have the molecule moving in the same way but with frequencies of $4.5$, $7.5$ or $10.5$ THz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the extent that you can treat the vibrations of a molecule as perfectly harmonic (which is only an approximation), there will be some number of independent normal modes of vibration, each with their own frequency $\omega_i$.  (For instance, a water molecule has three independent modes of vibration: the symmetric and anti-symmetric stretch modes and the bending mode.) The energy associated with each of these normal modes follows the standard quantum simple harmonic oscillator formula, i.e.,
$$
E_{n_i}^{(i)} = \hbar\omega_i\left(n_i+\frac{1}{2}\right)\,.
$$
Therefore, the total energy of vibration, given that the molecule is in one of its vibrational *eigen*states, is just the sum of these terms, i.e.,
$$
E = \sum_{i}E_{n_i}^{(i)} = \sum_i\hbar\omega_i\left(n_i+\frac{1}{2}\right)\,.
$$

Comment: Fascinating, thanks. Btw what do you you mean by "*the vibrations of a molecule as perfectly harmonic (which is only an approximation)*"? Do you mean it would likely take an infinite set of modes to fully model vibrations of a molecule?

Comment: For a degree of freedom $q$ to behave harmonically its Hamiltonian has to be of the form $H \sim q^2$, this is never true in practice and only a good approximation in some neighborhood of values.